# Intellij Says "Unresolved variable or type" but it's defined using @name

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

This is ths code:

```
/**
 * @name Me
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {Number} minVer
 * @property {Number} maxVer
 */

/** @type {Me}  the moshe*/
var y;
```

Why IntelliJ says that {Me} is not defined?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ do you have? Your example works perfectly fine in 14.1.2

Comment: 14.0.2. I will test on your version

Comment: Happen also in 14.1.2

Answer (score 5):

If you use [`@typedef`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) instead of `@name`, IntelliJ will be happier:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Me
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {Number} minVer
 * @property {Number} maxVer
 */

/** @type {Me}  the moshe*/
var y;
```

Comment: Almost there ;) You have forgotten to actually state the type in the `@typedef` line, it has to be `@typedef {Object} Me`. Otherwise, you get a warning in IntelliJ: "Unresolved variable or type Me". Still, your example gave me the decisive hint for the right solution, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have configured the correct javascript version:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#ws_js_choose_language_version_multiple_versions